# How can I upload the image file with axios?

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, axios

Do I need to change the model below to upload images to `django restapi`?

```
function axmethod(url, method, options) {
  if (options !== undefined) {
    var {
      params = {}, data = {}
    } = options
  } else {
    params = data = {}
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const config = {

    }
    axios({
      url,
      method,
      params,
      data,

    }).then(res => {
      resolve(res)
    }, res => {
      reject(res)
    })
  })
}
```

please help if I need to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two things that might be the key:

1. In order to upload a image, you need to specify `contentType: "multipart/form-data"` in your config object
2. The uploaded data needs to be a FormData object. Let's say you have an object `myCurrentData` which contains a name string and the file itself. You can transform it using:

   ```
   const data = new FormData();
   Object.entries(myCurrentData).forEach(([key, value]) => data.append(key, value || ""));
   ```